# adding a paragraph in list items breaking aligment in unordered list

Tags: html, css, list, listview, unordered

i'm trying to make an unordered list like this

[image]

but as soon as in input the content part under a list-item , the third list-item shifts up and ends up looking like this

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li> | </li>
    <li> .01 </li>
    <li class="text">
      <label> First</label>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita qui ipsa dolor. 
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px 0; 
}
.wrapper ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 50px;
}
.wrapper ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.wrapper ul .text{
  text-align: left;
}
```

Can you let me know how to fix it or is there anything i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px 0; 
}
.wrapper ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;      /* add this line */
}
.wrapper ul li{
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.wrapper ul .text{
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: thanks , it works.. but how?  flex works on child elements and since no property set for the child element how is it taking that change?

Comment: `display: inline-block` ist trying to display the block elements as text. Therefore they are aligned at the bottom. That is why it moves the elements up. `display: flex` is just a different aproach in getting the items next to each other without `inline`. Maybe `float: left` would work fine aswell.

Comment: tried that , but when im trying to populate the list the list-items are stacking horizontally and not vertically, tried flex:1 nothing changes.

Comment: yeah but `flex: 1` will only work if you use `display: flex` on the parent element.

Comment: thanks a lot man ,one last thing is this the right way to go ? or should i have tried with tables instead?

Comment: You definitely should try to avoid tables as much as possible.
Now if you want to make this example responsive you could simply float the items beneath each other.

In my opinion that is definitely the right approach!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124965/discussion-between-aaron-mahlke-and-tankit88).